# SED bash script Assistance

Tags: bash, sed, grep, command-line-interface

I'm trying to follow who my friend is following (all 1,522 of them)

and a got a text file with from his twitter page and I want to see just the last word of a line that begins with `@`.

Example:

```
Podcaster, broadcaster and tech pundit. The Tech Guy on the Premiere Radio
    Networks. Live at live.twit.tv For my link feed follow @links_for_twit
```

(Line-wrapped to remove hateful horizontal scrollbar.)

I want that to turn into `@links_for_twit`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use awk instead:

```
 awk '$NF ~ /^@/ {print $NF}'
```

Answer (score 1):

You mean, like:

```
grep -o '@[a-zA-Z_0-9]*$' tweets.txt
```

?

Comment: This won't work in the case that there is an @ embedded in the last word. For example, "user@domain.com"

Comment: @Swiss: `.` isn't in the character class.

Comment: This will work only if Twitter only allows pretty boring user names. Simple though, `grep -o` is a useful tool to be reminded of. :)

Comment: @ruakh: It still has the issue with matching embedded @ symbols. Something like `grep -o '\s*@\w*$'` might work, but then you would be including the whitespace. I'm not sure there is a clean way to do this with grep.

Comment: @Swiss: I guess I just don't see why that's a problem. There will be false positives with any approach; embedded `@`s seem very unlikely to me.

Comment: @sarnold: I found on Google a claim that "The only characters you can use [in a Twitter username] are uppercase and lowercase letters, numbers, and the underscore character ( _ )", so that's what I went with. (I'm not sure if Twitter supports non-ASCII usernames, though. Obviously my pattern doesn't support Unicode; I don't know if it needs to.)

Answer (score 1):

If you're wanting to use sed, try this:

`sed -n 's/.*\(@.*\)/\1/p'`

`-n`: don't print anything unless asked

`s/.*\(@.*\)`: capture everything after the last '@' in the line

`/\1/`: replace the whole line with the captured bit

`p`: print if a substitution was made

Hope that helps

**EDIT:** I just saw the complaint below about email addresses.  you can add `\s` just before the @ to ensure there's a space: `sed -n 's/.*\s(@.*\)/\1/p'`

Answer (score 0):

If you have GNU grep, you could use a Perl-flavoured regex to ensure the `@` is at the start of a word:

```
grep -Po '(?<=^|\s)@\w+' filename
```